# PowerShell script causes "The context has expired and can no longer be used. (Exception from HRESULT: X80090317)" issue

Tags: 2013, error, powershell

Currently I have 3 different SharePoint environments; DEV,UAT and PROD. These environments have same server topology and same software installations.

I populate some SharePoint lists and a SQL Server database with PowerShell. PowerShell script works fine under DEV and UAT. It also works well on PROD. However, whenever I run the script in the PROD, SharePoint site starts displaying;

> Sorry, something went wrong
>
> The context has expired and can no longer be used. (Exception from HRESULT:X80090317)

There is no such problem neither on DEV nor UAT. I assume that some configurations are different on the PROD but I couldn't find which ones they are.

What is the problem here? How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to the above answer but check if the web application time zone and the server time zone are identical, you could refer this article:
[Time zone issue](http://blog.cloudshare.com/2012/10/22/how-to-fix-sharepoint-2013-web-application-error-the-context-has-expired-and-can-no-longer-be-used/)

Comment: They are not matching! Let me make them identical. Thanks

Comment: @Manu, the URL above is broken. Page not found.
The time zone is the same in web application and server, but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: It was fine when I posted, it seems they have moved the article here: https://support.cloudshare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200701125-Sorry-something-went-wrong-The-context-has-expired-and-can-no-longer-be-used

Answer (score 0):

The problem in my environment was that that it was because of **default zone settings of the web application**

Take a look of this link:[The content has expired](http://www.sharepoint-journey.com/the-content-has-expired-and-can-no-longer-be-used.html)

Comment: Yes, I know this is related to "default zone settings of the web application". But I don't change this configuration with script. It's already configured.